# Flink Cannot load user class on running from IDE

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink application and generating a fat jar with all its dependencies I can submit it successfully on the remote cluster, using `flink run` command. Trying to submit the application on IntelliJ IDE, I faced the folloing error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot load user class: MyFlink$1
ClassLoader info: URL ClassLoader:
    file: '/tmp/blobStore-0fe289f8-b35b-4666-8402-67f9f6a22f55/cache/blob_3fd776b533f2268b6cf7ef1cc62b187bc4513c99' (valid JAR)
Class not resolvable through given classloader.
```

I packaged dependencies in a single jar file and pass it in `createRemoteEnvironment` method.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(
            "jobmanager", 6123, 2,
            "FlinkProcessing_dependencies.jar"
    );
```

How can I disaper this error?

**Notice:** Passing all user-defined classes in addition to dependencies, it runs successfully, but I don't want to pass the classes jars and export a jar file each time I change my classes!